# Cannot find the object "dbo.Addresses" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nuget-package

My code is like this

```
 public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int PostNo { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }

}

 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MearnIt.Models.Address> Addresses { get; set; }
   }
```

And when i run Update-Database command on nuget package manager console it hrows this error.

```
Cannot find the object "dbo.Addresses" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

I have no Idea why it's throwing an error like this. Can anyone point out what's going wrong herE?

Comment: The exception tells you to check two things. Do that first *on the database the migration connects to*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the command line:

Open **file explorer** and browse to the folder for your project (within the **src** folder). Hold down **shift** on the keyboard and at the same time right click on File explorer and select **"Open command window here"**

A command windows should appear. Now, enter the following command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial.
```

wait until the command has finished executing. Followed by entering:

```
donet ef database update
```

Remember in order to make changes to the database you will need to delete the Initial.cs file in the Data/Migrations folder **before** you run the commands. Now run the commands again.

Hope that helps.